# How to add gateway subnet for Point to Site VPN? - The specified address range overlaps with subnet default

Tags: azure, vpn

I'm trying to create point to site VPN. I have created new virtual network. Its address space is 172.16.0.0/24
I'm trying to do step 2 of linked article to add new gateway subnet. However I cannot figure out what is wrong with my address range. If I add 172.16.0.0/24 it says "The specified address range overlaps with subnet default which has a range of 172.16.0.0/24". If I modify IP I get "is not valid CIDR block. Use 172.16.0.0/24 instead."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal

Comment: The root reason is Azure VPN gateway needs a independent subnet, when you create VNet on Portal, by default default subnet uses whole ip ranges. You could not create a new subnet, so you get the warn log.

Comment: When you create VM, modify VNet adress range to `172.16.0.0/16`, default subnet uses `172.16.0.0/24`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to extend your vnet address space, say change it to 172.16.0.0/23 and then you can add 172.16.1.0/24 as your gateway subnet.

You really need to read up on basics of subnetting if you don't understand the concept behind it. its simple and useful.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/solutions_advisory_board/2016/12/01/calculating-the-gateway-subnet-address-space-for-azure-virtual-networks/

Comment: I further suggest to add just 172.16.1.0/24 to the address space instead as if you use default settings other resource group with VM are likely to want to claim a 172.16.x.0/24 where x wasn't used yet.

Comment: https://www.xarg.org/tools/subnet-calculator/ Use a calculator if you are confused about the IP range you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the address space by adding another address range CIDR block by clicking "Address Space" inside the settings of Virtual Network Resource, above the "Subnets" link.
You can add as many ranges as you want to extend your Virtual Network.